# Create Fishnet option

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, feature-class, vector-grid, data-management

I'm using ArcGIS and closely following this tutorial http://economics.mit.edu/files/8945 to process data in ArcMap. My problem arises because in my software I can't find the Create Fishnet option in Data Management Tools-->Features Class. Here is a picture of what it looks like

[image]

I have searched in the Internet but no one seems to be having the same issue. The coordinate system is the standard WGS 1984 Web Mercator.

Comment: I think it got moved at some point. In 10.5, at least, it's in the Sampling toolset under Data Management. That's...not where I remember it.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of looking for the Create Fishnet (or any other) tool in ArcToolbox, I recommend using the Search window to search for and open it.

If you are curious to know which toolset it is located in for the ArcGIS version that you are using then after searching for it you can click on the green link returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite weird since Fishnet is a basic function of ArcGIS.

I run ArcGIS 10.2 on Windows 10 (64-bit) and search "create fishnet" on the Search window. Here is what I got.

[image: Search create fishnet]

Here are my recommendations:

1. Go to ArcGIS for Desktop help on Start menu, and search Fishnet. Check if anything there.
2. Open Customize -> Customize mode -> Commands, and search fishnet to see if any command occurs.
   [image]
3. Repair the ArcGIS installation to ensure the entire software is installed.